# I want the Response from Web App should go via application gateway only

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have a Azure Web app in Standard S3 tier and I want the Response from Web App should go Via application gateway. Because my customer will only whitelist single dedicated IP address. In App service we get rage to shared outbound dedicated IP addresses. I read the many blogs it is suggesting to use ASE environment for dedicated IP address for App service.

Please suggest the workaround if any so that my App service will response from single dedicated IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

App Service Environment (ASE) is best suited for scenarios where you want to limit traffic to closed networks and/or access on-premise data through a VPN/Express Route.

In your case, you could go with either [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) or [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) in front of your App Service. Your customer would have to just whitelist the public IP of the service you choose.

Also, you could lock down your App Service just for requests coming from the same public IP, to disallow direct requests.